# UIStackView width & height not changing following elements addition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview

## Context

I am trying to create UIStackView programatically, but it isn't showing at all.

To test, I created 2 small `UIView`s that I add to the `UIStackView`.

#### I tried

- Adding, constraints to the `UIStackView`
- Using `layoutIfNeeded`
- Using `layoutSubviews`

But nothing is working.

## Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var contentStack = UIStackView()

    @IBOutlet weak var mainScroll: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        contentStack.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.05882352963, green: 0.180392161, blue: 0.2470588237, alpha: 1)
        contentStack.axis = .vertical
        contentStack.spacing = 0
        contentStack.alignment = .top
        contentStack.distribution = .equalSpacing

        let a_view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 30))
        a_view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4666666687, green: 0.7647058964, blue: 0.2666666806, alpha: 1)
        contentStack.addArrangedSubview(a_view)

        let b_view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 40))
        b_view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9607843161, green: 0.7058823705, blue: 0.200000003, alpha: 1)
        contentStack.addArrangedSubview(b_view)

        mainScroll.addSubview(contentStack)
        contentStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainScroll.topAnchor).isActive = true
        contentStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainScroll.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        contentStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainScroll.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        contentStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainScroll.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mainScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: contentStack.frame.height)

        print("Stack Content Size: (\(contentStack.frame.width), \(contentStack.frame.height))");
    }
}
```

## Output

[image: Output]

## Question

After reading the documentation, I assume that `UIStackView`'s height & width both adapt following the elements contained the size of the stack view after the view addition, it is `Stack Content Size: (0.0, 0.0)`?

Comment: you have a problem in IB , Aslo **translateAutoresizingMaskIntoconstarints = false** should be for views added programmatically

Comment: What problem in Interface Builder?

Comment: Also, I tried putting **translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false** on UIStackView & on both UIViews but getting nothing

Comment: I suspect the issue has to do with using a `UIScrollView` and AutoLayout. They're tough to get working together. Here's a technical [Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) from Apple on the topic. Also, side note: I dont think you can actually set the background color of a `UIStackView` as it's a non-drawing view. Thinking that you can set the background color might be throwing off your debugging process.

Comment: You should not be setting `contentSize` manually.

Comment: @Sulthan How so? I must be adding a contentSize for the scroll view, & I want to define in such a way that it equals the height of the UIStackView, in short I want a scrollable stack view, do you know a better way to do it?

Comment: @JaredH Thanks I will be reading the note, for the background color, I was doing so for debugging purposes, to see if the stackview is really put on the view & its size, do you know of a better way to visually debug the existence & size of the stackview?

Comment: @kagawish The `Debug View Hierarchy` mode will help you to some extent. You can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html). Just remember the golden rule with UIStackViews: intrinsic content size. I've been in your exact same position before! :)

Comment: @JaredH Will take a look on `Debug View Hierarchy`, yeah, I am actually reading about `intrinsic content size`. Thanks

Comment: @kagawish With autolayout, the size of the scrollable content should be taken from the constraints. Basically, since the `contentSize` should be the height of the stackview, you should set the height of the *stackview* to the values you want.

Comment: @Sulthan For the *stackview* when you say height, you mean frame height or a height constraint? And if I set the height constraints on the *stackview*, will the contentSize for the scrollView automatically adapt to have a height equal to the *stackView*'s height?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting the constraints for the a_view and b_view like below

```
let a_view = UIView()
a_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
a_view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
a_view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

Stack views use intrinsic content size, so use layout constraints to define the dimensions of the views.

If this doesn't work then i suspect there could be some problems with the scrollview constraints.

Comment: It works, I thought adding a frame is enough to define the size of the view, but it seems that adding a width an height constraint is necessary, do you know why?

Comment: As @Akshay said - `UIStackView` uses the intrinsic content size of the arranged subviews to determine the size.